# Mount Google Cloud Storage Bucket to Instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

How can I mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a disk or folder with a standard path such as `~/myBucket` on a Google Compute instance?

Everything is in the same project with full access.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the new beta `gcsfuse` this is now possible.

```
gcsfuse myBucket ~/path/to/mount
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

Comment: Is there any way to do this in windows?

Comment: @wayofthefuture given your name your question confuses me. Kidding, you should be able to use mingw or something.  Docker would be great.

Comment: @wayofthefuture haha :D mac or nix?

Comment: mac for dev, nix for server :) i'm having a time though learning the command prompt

Comment: @wayofthefuture Learning nix style terminal is one of the best things you can do.  Now your on mac never look back

Answer (score 1):

install  gcsfuse on your virtual instance.

then

```
$ gcsfuse {{bucket name}} ~{{mounting path}}
```

https://medium.com/google-cloud/scheduled-mirror-sync-sftp-to-gcs-b167d0eb487a

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount gcs on instance permanently then refer to this doc which says
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md

If you would prefer to mount the file system automatically,
`you may need to pass the x-systemd.requires=network-online.target or _netdev option to ensure that gcsfuse waits for the network system to be ready prior to mounting`

`my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,user`
You can also mount the file system automatically as a non-root user by specifying the options uid and/or gid:

`my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,_netdev,allow_other,uid=1001,gid=1001`